# Python Dash/Plotly download excel with multiple Input/State/Output - being called with wrong Input

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have The states below which are being called with **Input('submit-button_table', 'n_clicks')] button**,

and the first 2 outputs are executed,

but the issue is that my 2nd input **[Input('btn_xlsx', 'n_clicks')**,

and the 3rd output **Output('download-dataframe-xlsx', 'data')], # download excel**

are being called when I press on the 1st **Input submit-button_table** as well, altogether.

How to set my download excel Output to get called only when I press on Input('btn_xlsx', 'n_clicks')

```
@app.callback(

[Output('table','columns'), # 1st Output, excel columns

 Output('table', 'data'), #2nd Output, excel table

Output('download-dataframe-xlsx', 'data')], #3rd Output, download 
#excel

[Input('btn_xlsx', 'n_clicks'), #2nd Input, click on download

Input('submit-button_table', 'n_clicks')], #1st Input, click submit 
#for the states below to call

[State('symbol', 'value'),

 State('yes_no', 'value'),

State('my_date_picker_table', 'start_date'),

State('my_date_picker_table', 'end_date'),

State('delete', 'value'),

State('percentage', 'value'),

State('points', 'value')],

prevent_initial_call=True,

)
```